# node:module.js err549 Cannot find module

Tags: node.js, windows

Installed node version 8.11.2. When I type

```
>node-v 
v8.11.2

>npm -v
6.5.0
```

When I run a sample js file I am getting below error

```
c:\node>node index.js
module.js:549
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'c:\node\index.js'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:547:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:474:25)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:693:10)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:191:16)
    at bootstrap_node.js:612:3
```

Comment: [mvce](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) please.

Comment: var http = require("http");

http.createServer(function (request, response) {
   
   response.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
   
   
   response.end('Hello World\n');
}).listen(8081);

console.log('Server running at http://127.0.0.1:8081/');